# Dont know how to select a few records from a table as utf8

Tags: mysql

I don't have phpMyAdmin installed in my web site.

Sometimes I was doing some select SQL command at the backend,
 
but when I typed in this command to show all records from table Users:

```
select * from Users;
```

The records were printed as ???? | ??? ??? ??? |.

I don't want to make any permanent changes to the charset in the database,
so, how is it possible to temporarily displayed a few records as utf8 when needed?

Comment: Where did you type the statement, in mysql console? If yes, under which OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**> CONVERT()**

provides a way to convert data between different character sets

example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(newvalue USING utf8);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put 'N' before your queries like

```
 select * from User where id = N'یونیکد'
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the mysql `CONVERT`-statement, i think thats what you are looking for. if i remember right, the syntax is like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(username USING utf8) FROM users...;
```